# LINQ sort collection with IF statement

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sort the collection before processing. I used to use this method:

```
foreach (var item in Items.OrderBy(i => i.property1))
{
 ...
}
```

Now i need to sort it by **property2**, if property values is equals between two items. Is there any method to do that logic via LINQ expression?

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+orderby+two+properties will give you more if duplicate is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
foreach (var item in Items.OrderBy(i => i.property1).ThenBy(i => i.property2))
{
 ...
}
```